# Apply Flask changes to Apache2 server without restart

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask

Everytime I make a change to Flask in any .py file on my Apache2 server, the changes don't go into effect until I run `sudo service apache2 restart`.

This was fine when I only had one application on the server but now I have a couple and I'd like to avoid restarting the entire server whenever I want to make a Flask change.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried graceful?

Comment: Ahh I didn't know this existed. DUhhh thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks @AllinOne: graceful restart of apache where traffic wont be impacted, using

```
apachectl -k graceful
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do development in your main Apache. Presuming you are using mod_wsgi, use mod_wsgi-express instead and run a separate instance from the command line during development. There is even an option on mod_wsgi-express to auto reload processes when your code changes. See:

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/05/using-modwsgi-express-as-development.html